# SQL Server - Strange round behaviour when using variable vs just value

Tags: sql, sql-server, floating-point, rounding

I'm facing this strange issue in SQL Server when dividing a float that it's stored in variable vs when just use the value.

The case is the following:

```
DECLARE @FLOAT FLOAT = 6.80
print ROUND(@FLOAT / 2, 2, 0);  
print ROUND(@FLOAT / 2, 2, 1);
```

It prints:

```
3.4
3.39
```

The second ROUND that truncates the value is giving an wrong value. It should be 3.4 and not 3.39.

But when I use the value without the variable it works properly:

```
print ROUND(6.80 / 2, 2, 0);  
print ROUND(6.80 / 2, 2, 1);
```

It prints:

```
3.400000
3.400000
```

Can anybody help me understanding this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not strange at all, you're using a `float` for the first expression, and a `decimal` for the second, you should be expecting such behaviour. Base 2 and Base 10 numbers act quite differently.

Comment: Thank you for your quick comment. I'm sorry but I don't think I understood what you mean by "Base 2 and Base 10 numbers act quite differently" related to float.

Comment: Base 2 or Binary numbers vs Base 10 or Decimal numbers. Non-integer values often can't be store accurately with the former. Have a read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is expected. In the first expression you are using a `float`, and in the latter literal `decimal`. These two data types are *very* different. The former is a Base 2 value, and the latter Base 10.

`6.80` *cannot* be stored precisely using Base 2, and so it's *actual* value is closer to the value `6.79999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875`. As you can see, this is *ever so slightly* less than `6.8` and so when you divide that number by `2`, you get a number ever so slightly less than `3.40`,probably `3.399999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375`.

As a result `ROUND` is rounding the number correctly, as the above value rounded to 2 digits ***is*** `3.39` *not* `3.40`.

For the literal, `6.80` is represented exactly, and so is `6.80 / 2` (`3.40`) so when you round that number again to 2 decimal places, you still get `3.40`